# Jquery .ajax contact form works, but doesn't fire success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am testing to make an email form with jquery and ajax. The email processes and sends fine but the success function in .ajax does not fire. I am really new to all this functionality so I am unsure what could be wrong. I am so greatful for your help! fyi (#blah) is just an indicator

```
    $(function() {  
  $(".button").click(function() {  
    // validate and process form here 
  $('#blah').hide();
      var name = $("input#name").val();  
        var email = $("input#email").val();  
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();   
    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;  
//alert (dataString);return false;  
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "http://www.joepolitic.com/contactform.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
    $('#second').hide(); 
  }  
});  
return false;  

  });  
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

// get posted data into local variables
$EmailFrom = "First Facility Contact Form";
$EmailTo = "xxx@xxx.com";
$Subject = "Contact";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$Phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone'])); 

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Phone: ";
$Body .= $Phone;
$Body .= "\n";


// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");


?>
```

Comment: Use Firefox + Firebug. Open the NET tab and watch your XHR request. You can see if it is successful or not.

Comment: You might try `echo $success;` at the end of your file

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your code to include the following:

```
  success: function(result) {
    alert(result);  
    $('#second').hide(); 
  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    alert(xhr.statusText);
  }
```

Comment: And you said that the email is sent without any errors?  The above code should grab the response from the php file and alert the output from the file.  If the alert is not firing then that indicates that something is happen in the AJAX interaction.

Comment: with your extra code I did receive an alert box saying "error" but the email was once again sent successfully